# In kendo grid Update button is not firing

Tags: view, kendo-grid

I have Kendo UI inline Grid. It read and populate the grid properly. but when i press edit and changes in any column and press update then update event is not firing. and it also not calling controller method.

my view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({  
        transport:
            {
                read:
                    {
                        url: "/Student/StudentGrid",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET"
                    },
                update:
                    {
                        url: "@Url.Action("EditStudentDetails")",                                                      
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST"
                    },
 parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
    if (operation != "read" && options) {
                        if (operation != "destroy") {
                            return JSON.stringify({
                                studentViewModel: options
                            });
                        }
                        else if (operation == "destroy") {
                            return JSON.stringify({
                                id: options.Id
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
 parse: function (test) {

            if (test.success) {
                if (test.type != "read") {
                    alert(test.message);
                    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
                return test.data;
            }
            else {
                alert(test.message);
                return [];
            }
        }

    })
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filterable: true,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
          {
              field: "Id",
              width: 120,
              visible: false
          },
       {
           field: "Name",
           title: "Student Name",
           editor: AutocompleteName,
           width: 180

       },
       {
           field: "CourseName",
           title: "Course Name",
           editor: CourseDropDownEditor,
           width: 200,
           template: "#=CourseName#"
       },
        {
            command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"
        }
        ],
        editable: "inline"
    });
```

What i did wrong in this and when i click on edit button it is changing to editable mode but when i click on update it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Is any of your cell text has HTML tags like "<" or ">", remove them and click on update and check the update event fire.